# how can I make this (sticky, full-width) navbar using Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have spent literally hours (I'm new to coding) trying to replicate this navbar (https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/MyResume/) but couldn't do it.
I'm not sure if it requires JavaScript knowledge (I only know HTML, CSS, and Bootstrap).
Any help how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called "ScrollSpy". You can find it in the documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy).

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-example">
  ...
  <div id="navbar-example">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>
  ...
</body>
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#navbar-example' })
```

Comment: thnks Jacob, that helped a lot.
I just have a question: how do I center the links? I made this but the links or the tabs are on the left, how can I center them?

Comment: You welcome. You can do it by CSS class. Just put your link in a div thar refers to this class: ".link-wrapper { display:block; text-align:center }" or you can use this html tag: <center></center> and placing your link in between.

Comment: thanks again. I tried the CSS class, but the links actually stacked on top of each other